# General questions related to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm quite new to this and would like to ask some expert opinions so I can improve myself

Some questions:

- Is tag firing priority always needed (e.g. for cookie consent?
- Should I always fire a cookie initialisation trigger or is a page view trigger enough?
- Any opinions on data layer as a value versus data layer variable?
- Any opinion on using trigger groups? is there a more streamlined approach? Is a custom event better?
- Click classes versus custom events: do click classes suffice?

Your input is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> Is tag firing priority always needed (e.g. for cookie consent?

No. Tag firing priority determines the order in which tags will be fired, when there are multiple tags on same event. A high priority will not ensure, that the tag will finish his execution first, because all tags are executed asynchronously. It might be the case, that one tag starts first, but then takes a lot of time until it is finished, whereas other tags can finish earlier. Regarding cookie consent: If you mean to fire a consent layer within GTM and to set a priority for that (priority will be meaningless, if there are no other tags on the same trigger), I would not recommend this. Better integrate the consent layer directly on the page.

> Should I always fire a cookie initialisation trigger or is a page view
> trigger enough?

Depends on the use case. If you are firing marketing tags, then page view trigger is fine. If you still want to fire a consent layer through GTM, then use the "Consent Initialization" trigger for that. The typical use case for the "Consent Initialization" trigger is to push the standard commands of Google Consent Mode into dataLayer.

> Any opinions on data layer as a value versus data layer variable?

If you don't plan to rename the global object, then it's fine to use it as value within your variables.

> Any opinion on using trigger groups? is there a more streamlined
> approach? Is a custom event better?

I am not a fan of trigger groups because they fire only once on a page, even if the triggers listed within the group fire again. Also with trigger groups you won't have a lot of data in the datalayer (basically its just the event name and a unique ID). With custom events you have more control and possibilities.

> Click classes versus custom events: do click classes suffice?

You can use both, but as click classes can change on the website I would go with custom events.